# Switching between a JavaFX scene and a non-JavaFX scene

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I've created a game and I wanted to add a start screen to it, I've added it using FXML as well as added 2 buttons (start and quit).

Upon pressing the start button, I want the game to load and switch scenes to the start of the game. I've got a rough idea of how to do it but i'm struggling a bit as my SampleController class does not know anything about starting up the game etc, as all of that code (as well as the code to load up the initial start menu) is in my Main class, so this is the kind of thing I tried:

```java
@FXML
void startGame(ActionEvent event) {
    background.start();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    start();
}
```

I tried doing it using a function to switch scenes and it didn't work, also tried to get the information about the stage using `Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();` as I saw it as a possible solution from a YouTube video however it was telling me that Node cannot be resolved to a type.

This is my code:

Main

```java
public class Main extends Application 
{
AnimationTimer timer;
MyStage background;
Animal animal; //This is the player/frog that is moved

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/startMenu.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
    primaryStage.show();

    //All the code after this point is essentially what I want to be executed upon pressing the button
    background = new MyStage();
    Scene scene  = new Scene(background,600,800);
    BackgroundImage froggerback = new BackgroundImage("file:resources/froggerBackground.png");
    background.add(froggerback);


    //At this point, a bunch of code like the line below is called to add in the different obstacles to the background
    background.add(new Turtle(500, 376, -1, 130, 130));


    //background.start();
    //primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    //primaryStage.show();
    //start();
}
```

SampleControllerClass

```java
public class SampleController {

@FXML
private Button quitButton;

@FXML
private Button startButton;

@FXML
void startGame(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void quitGame(ActionEvent event) {

}
```

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using JavaFX in all cases, you don't have "a JavaFX scene and a non-JavaFX scene".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. Your `SampleController` is the FXML controller which links the `startButton` for a game.
2. In your SampleController, you have an action event handler defined for your start button `startGame`.
3. You have another FXML file defined for your game layout, called `game.fxml`.

Then, you can get the current scene from the start button and replace the root of the scene with the new parent derived when loading the `game.fxml`:

```
@FXML
private Button startButton;

@FXML
void startGame(ActionEvent event) {
    Parent gameRoot = FXMLLoader.load(
        getClass().getResource("game.fxml")
    );
    startButton.getScene().setRoot(gameRoot); 
}
```

You don't need to create a new scene or stage (unless that is something you really want to do for some other reason).  If you really need to do that (which you probably don't), then that is outside the scope of what I am supplying in this answer.

Comment: My game layout is just made in my Main class and it has hardcoded values for the X and Y positions etc, as well as having a bunch of other classes for things